# Reduce array to objects with nested keys for passing a search query to Model.find in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, reduce

I have an array of user-entered search parameters that need to be sent as a query string in the header of a fetch() request to query MongoDB with Mongoose. The array can contain up to 20-30 objects (search filters) and looks like this:

```
filters = [{…}, {…}]
0: {fieldName: "city", searchString: "Rome", searchMode: "$eq"}
1: {fieldName: "country", searchString: "Spain", searchMode: "$ne"}
```

I need to reduce this filters array to an array of objects, each containing a search filter that can be passed as the filter argument to Model.find() in Mongoose. The objects will be stringified and sent to the back-end via req.query from a fetch() request.

The objects need to be of the following syntax:

```
{city: { $eq: Rome } }
```

so I can pass this search filter to MongoDB from Mongoose like so:

```
db.customers.find( { city: { $eq: "Rome" } } )
```

So far I have figured out how I can reduce the initial array to an array of "key: value" objects:

```
const jsonObj = filters.reduce((r, { fieldName, searchString }) => (r[fieldName] = searchString, r), {})
```

Can anyone please help reduce the array to this form:

```
{city: { $eq: Rome } }
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting close to the answer, just need some change in the reducer function:

```js
let jsonObj = [
  {fieldName: "city", searchString: "Rome", searchMode: "$eq"},
  {fieldName: "country", searchString: "Spain", searchMode: "$ne"}
];

let query = jsonObj.reduce((acc, {fieldName, searchString, searchMode}) => {
  acc[fieldName] = { [searchMode]: searchString };
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(query)
```